# FCM messages not reaching device when sent from server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement FCM in my app. Right now, I am able to receive messages when i send them from firebase app console. But when i try to send messages from my server, the message is not getting delivered to the phone. However, I am getting a success status after sending message from the server and it shows delivered to 1 device. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Manifest File:

```
</application>

<service
    android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>


<service
    android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action     android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle app:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build.gradle project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'



    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Code:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    ShowNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

private void ShowNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentIntent(pendingintent);

    NotificationManagerCompat manager =(NotificationManagerCompat) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());

}



}





public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {


    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    System.out.println("TOKEN   " + token);
}
}
```

Server Side Code:

```
function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = ***********************************',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}


$tokens = array(); 
$tokens[] = "***********************************************";

$message = array("message" => " DEEPAK PUSH TEST MESSAGE");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status;
```

Comment: Post your code/logcat.You should give More information

Comment: please make sure you added this **google-services** file and it contains firebase url `project_info": {
    "project_number": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "firebase_url": "https://projectid.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "projectid",
    "storage_bucket": "projectid.appspot.com"
  }` also check other parameters exist in this file. then try your code.

Comment: Are you using Local server like Xampp etc or any free web host?
If you can send message(Notification) using FCM console then pretty much chances that your android app code have no problem. Post your php scripts for Registering tokens to your server database and the Script to send post request to FCM server. I had similar problem and After changing my php code 1000times I used my XAMPP locat host and the same code working like charm. Problem was in my free webhost server settings not in my code. May be this is case with you too ;)

Comment: It would be useful to see the request that you are using to send the message.

Comment: Guys, sorry for the late reply. I have posted the server side code. please have a look at code.

Comment: Do you know if onMessageReceived is being called at all? Maybe add a log statement in there to be sure?

Comment: The onMessageRecieved method is not getting called in any case, ie whenever i send message from the fcm console, I am getting the notification, but the log is not getting printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. The format in which I was generating json, was wrong. I didnt put the payload under notification tag. Post that change it started working. Thanks a lot guys, for all your suggestions.

Comment: can you post your update or modified question. it will be more helpful.